# How to use html file as htmlBody?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

**How to use html file as htmlBody??**

I know that I can use MailApp.sendEmail to sent an email.
And I know I can set htmlBody with html code.
However my html code are to long and have many lines,so I want to write them in a extra html file not just using one gs file with so many "+".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample script? Please think of this as one of several answers.

When you put HTML body to your script editor as a HTML file, you can achieve it by using `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile()`. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script :

```
var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("### HTML filename without extension ###").getBlob();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "### Your e-mail address ###",
  subject: "sample subject",
  htmlBody: blob.getDataAsString()
});
```

#### References :

- [HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

If when you run the script, you want to update a table, you can use this sample script.

#### GAS :

```
var t = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("### HTML filename without extension ###");
t.data = ["sample1", "sample3", "sample3"];
var blob = t.evaluate().getBlob();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "### Your e-mail address ###",
  subject: "sample subject",
  htmlBody: blob.getDataAsString()
});
```

#### HTML :

```
<table>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= data[i] ?></td>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

#### References :

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: You can also use [createHtmlOutputFromFile().getContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getContent()) to get the `String` content of the [HTMLOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) that is returned from [createHtmlOutputFromFile(String)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String))

Comment: @random-parts Thank you for your additional information. In this situation, there are several ways. Also the HTML body can be read from files on Google Drive. Users can select from them.

Comment: Thank you very much,it's exactly what I need.And what if I need some html code to be dynamic,how can i do that?For example : fill a table.

Comment: @Zhiyong ZHOU You can create their HTML files on your script editor. So you can send mails by selecting the HTML file for ``HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)``. If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike You might misunderstand my comment since I expressed not clearly.I got it how to selecting the HTML file,what I still confuse is that how can I change  <table>'s innerhtml ,since my html code has tag <table> and I need to dynamicly fill the table every time I run the script.

Comment: @Zhiyong I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Wow!That's what I need.Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zhiyong Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I like to build these files in Ultraedit and store them on the google drive as a txt files and I extract them html as string as follows.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailaddress,
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: loadMyFile(filename,folderID)}
);

function loadMyFile(filename,folderID){
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file=fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  while(file.hasNext()){
    var fi=file.next();
    var target=fi.getName();
    if(target==filename){
      var s=fi.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```