# App script GmailApp not recognising html file when using a trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send emails using the GmailApp in app script. I have the email itself in a separate html file.

When I manual run the script it works fine. When I set up a trigger it cannot find the html file.

I am not sure what is going wrong. The code I am using to send the email is below.

```
 for (let i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
  const row = data[i]
  const email = row[0]
  const name = row[1]
  const token = row[12]
  Logger.log(email)

     
    
  let template =HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(mail_template)
  template.name = name
  template.email = email
  template.token = token


                     
  const message = template.evaluate().getContent()
  
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
    email, subject, '',
    {htmlBody: message, name: ''}
    
  
  )
```

Comment: please show us [mcve]

Comment: Its unclear to me how you pull in an html file into a script.  Share your script so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: I have now added the email part of the code

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the code, would you mind adding the execution log as well? I also believe knowing which type of trigger is it that you have would help in this situation.

Comment: I am using a time based trigger set for a specific time . The error message I am getting is,Exception: No HTML file named [object Object] was found.Thanks

Comment: Here is a solution thanks to @Tanaike.  I tested it with a 5 min trigger [How to use html file as htmlBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502894/how-to-use-html-file-as-htmlbody)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use html file as htmlBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502894/how-to-use-html-file-as-htmlbody)